# Maximum Score from Two Arrays | Which Test Case is this approach missing?

Tags: python, arrays, max, dynamic-programming, memoization

### Problem Statement

Given two integer arrays `A` and `B` of size `N` and `M` respectively. You begin with a score of `0`. You want to perform **exactly** `K` operations. On the `iᵗʰ` operation **(1-indexed)**, you will:

- Choose one integer `x` from **either the start or the end** of any one array, `A` or `B`. Remove it from that array
- Add `x` to score.

Return the **maximum** score after performing `K` operations.

---

### Example

> **Input**: `A = [3,1,2]`, `B = [2,8,1,9]` and `K=5`
> **Output**: `24`
>
> **Explanation**: An optimal solution is as follows:
>
> - Choose from end of `B`, add 9 to score. Remove 9 from `B`
> - Choose from start of `A`, add 3 to score. Remove 3 from `A`
> - Choose from start of `B`, add 2 to score. Remove 2 from `B`
> - Choose from start of `B`, add 8 to score. Remove 8 from `B`
> - Choose from end of `A`, add 2 to score. Remove 2 from `A`
>
> The total score is `9+3+2+8+2 = 24`

---

### Constraints

- 1 ≤ `N` ≤ 6000
- 1 ≤ `M` ≤ 6000
- 1 ≤ `A[i]` ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
- 1 ≤ `B[i]` ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
- 1 ≤ `K` ≤ `N`+`M`

---

### My Approach

Since, greedy *[choosing maximum end from both array]* approach is failing here *[because it will produce conflict when maximum end of both array is same]*, it suggests we have to look for all possible combinations. There will be overlapping sub-problems, hence DP!

Here is the `python` [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code for the same.

```py
A = [3,1,2]
N = len(A)

B = [2,8,1,9]
M = len(B)

K = 5

memo = {}

def solve(i,j, AL, BL):
    if (i,j,AL,BL) in memo:
        return memo[(i,j,AL,BL)]

    AR = (N-1)-(i-AL)
    BR = (M-1)-(j-BL)

    if AL>AR or BL>BR or i+j==K:
        return 0
    
    op1 = A[AL] + solve(i+1,j,AL+1,BL)
    op2 = B[BL] + solve(i,j+1,AL,BL+1)
    op3 = A[AR] + solve(i+1,j,AL,BL)
    op4 = B[BR] + solve(i,j+1,AL,BL)

    memo[(i,j,AL,BL)] = max(op1,op2,op3,op4)
    return memo[(i,j,AL,BL)]

print(solve(0,0,0,0))
```

In brief,

- `i` indicates that we have performed `i` operations from `A`
- `j` indicates that we have performed `j` operations from `B`
- Total operation is thus `i+j`
- `AL` indicates index on left of which which all integers of `A` are used. Similarly `AR` indicates index on right of which all integers of `A` used for operation.
- `BL` indicates index on left of which which all integers of `B` are used. Similarly `BR` indicates index on right of which all integers of `B` used for operation.

We are trying out all possible combination, and choosing maximum from them in each step. Also memoizing our answer.

---

### Doubt

The code worked fine for several test cases, but also failed for few. The message was **Wrong Answer** means there was no *Time Limit Exceed, Memory Limit Exceed, Syntax Error* or *Run Time Error*. This means there is some *logical error* only.

Can anyone help in identifying those Test Cases? And, also in understanding intuition/reason behind why this approach failed in some case?

---

Comment: @Nic3500 -- you can only draw from the ends of the arrays.  For instance, in the case of `[2,8,1,9]` your first two draws can not be 9, then 8.  The best you could do with two draws of this array is 9, and 2 (i.e. you can't draw 8 until it's at one end of the array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is failing because the Recursive Functions stops computing further sub-problems when either *"`AL` exceeds `AR`"* or *"`BL` exceeds `BR`"*.

> We should stop computing and `return 0` only when both of them are True. If either of *"`AL` exceeds `AR`"* or *"`BL` exceeds `BR`"* evaluates to False, means we can solve that sub-problem.

Moreover, one quick optimization here is that when `N+M==K`, in this case we can get maximum score by choosing all elements from both the arrays.

Here is the correct code!

```py
A = [3,1,2]
B = [2,8,1,9]
K = 5

N, M = len(A), len(B)

memo = {}

def solve(i,j, AL, BL):
    if (i,j,AL,BL) in memo:
        return memo[(i,j,AL,BL)]

    AR = (N-1)-(i-AL)
    BR = (M-1)-(j-BL)

    if i+j==K or (AL>AR and BL>BR):
        return 0

    ans = -float('inf')
    
    if AL<=AR:
        ans = max(A[AL]+solve(i+1,j,AL+1,BL),A[AR]+solve(i+1,j,AL,BL),ans)

    if BL<=BR:
        ans = max(B[BL]+solve(i,j+1,AL,BL+1),B[BR]+solve(i,j+1,AL,BL),ans)

    memo[(i,j,AL,BL)] = ans
    return memo[(i,j,AL,BL)]

if N+M==K:
    print(sum(A)+sum(B))
else:
    print(solve(0,0,0,0))
```

*[This answer was published taking help from [DarryIG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932826/15845697)'s Answer. The reason for publishing answer is to write code similar to code in question body. [DarryIG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932826/15845697)'s answer used different prototype for function]*

Answer (score 0):

Examples were posted code gives the wrong answer:

Example 1.

```
A = [1, 1, 1]
N = len(A)
B = [1, 1]
M = len(B)
K = 5
print(print(solve(0,0,0,0))) # Output: 4 (which is incorrect)
# Correct answer is 5
```

Example 2.

```
A = [1, 1]
B = [1]
N = len(A)
M = len(B)
K = 3
print(print(solve(0,0,0,0))) # Output: 2 (which is incorrect)
# Correct answer is 3
```

**Alternative Code**

```
def solve(A, B, k):
    def solve_(a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right, remaining_ops, sum_):
        '''
           a_left          - left pointer into A
           a_right         - right pointer in A
           b_left          - left pointer into B
           b_right        - right pointer into B
           remaining_ops  - remaining operations
           sum_           - sum from previous operations
        '''
        if remaining_ops == 0:
            return sum_                          # out of operations
        if a_left > a_right and b_left > b_right:
            return sum_                          # both left and right are empty
        
        if (a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right) in cache:
            return cache[(a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right)]
        
        max_ = sum_                               # init to current sum
        if a_left <= a_right:                     # A not empty
            max_ = max(max_, 
                solve_(a_left + 1, a_right, b_left, b_right, remaining_ops - 1, sum_ + A[a_left]),     # Draw from left of A
                solve_(a_left, a_right - 1, b_left, b_right, remaining_ops - 1, sum_ + A[a_right]))    # Draw from right of A
                
        if b_left <= b_right:                      # B not empty
            max_ = max(max_,
                solve_(a_left, a_right, b_left + 1, b_right, remaining_ops - 1, sum_ + B[b_left]),     # Draw from left of B
                solve_(a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right - 1, remaining_ops - 1, sum_ + B[b_right]))    # Draw from right of B
            
        cache[(a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right)] = max_                                               # update cache
        return cache[(a_left, a_right, b_left, b_right)]
    
    cache = {}
    return solve_(0, len(A) - 1, 0, len(B) - 1, k, 0)
```

**Tests**

```
print(solve([3,1,2], [2,8,1,9], 5) # Output 24
print(solve([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], 5) # Output 5
```

Comment: Thanks. This corner case can also be handled by `if N+M==K: return sum(A) + sum(B)` statement. Moreover, to readers, another logical error is in the base conditions. In my code, We can't return 0 when either of `AL > AR or BL > BR` is True. We should return 0 when **both** of them evaluates to True. If either of them is false, we should proceed evaluating sub-problem.